# Win10: Fast access to Start Menu shortcuts: How?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

On Win7 (and other versions), I can do this:

- Create a shortcut
- Add it to start menu with a unique first digit (say: 7)

Now, to launch that shortcut, I just hit Windows key; 7

No need to navigate, or press enter or anything. Two keystrokes and it is launched. I can do it with my eyes closed (and often do)

I have not figured out how to do that in win10.... how is it done?

Comment: As far as I knew, this shortcut was for the taskbar, not the start menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pin the shortcut as the leftmost item to the taskbar, then <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> as a keyboard combo will launch your shortcut.

If you already have the program running, then <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> will instead activate the program, but you can use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to launch a new instance.

To expand, the taskbar icons can be activated by number. So if you have three icons there (say Firefox, Explorer, and Visual Studio Code), <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> will start Firefox, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> will start Explorer, and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> will start Visual Studio Code.